# Export .csv file from .mat file generated with OpenModelica

Tags: python, openmodelica

I am trying to export a `.csv` file from a `.mat` file, which was generated with OpenModelica. The following code seems to work quite well:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy
x = loadmat('results.mat')
traj=x['data_2'][0]
numpy.savetxt("results.csv", traj, delimiter=",")
```

However, there is an issue that I cannot solve. The line `traj=x['data_2'][0]` is taking an array with the values (over time) of the first variable in the file (index is 0). The problem is that I cannot make a correspondence between the variable I am looking for and its index. Let's say that I want to print the values of a variable called "My_model.T". How do I know the index of this variable?

Answer (score 0):

The file format is described here: https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/1.17/technical_details.html#the-matv4-result-file-format

So you need to lookup the variable's name in the `name` matrix, then look in the dataInfo matrix to see if the variable is stored in `data_1` or `data_2` and which index it has in this matrix.

Edit: And since the title was how to create a CSV from MAT-file... You can do this from an OpenModelica .mos-script:

```
filterSimulationResults("M_res.mat", "M_res.csv", readSimulationResultVars("M_res.mat"))
```

Comment: I tried to print the "name" matrix, but it looks unreadable (from Python console).

Comment: Then print name transposed